# Place JavaScript data result to a form input value

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

OK, so I have the script that generates Latitude and Longitude from geolocation after onClick.  I now want those coordinates placed inside the users form value field after onClick, instead of innerHTML.

How would I go about doing this?  Would I still need to use innerHTML??

My form details:

```
<body>
<h1>Insert New Address</h1>
 <form id="myForm" method="post" action="index3.php">
 <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true">
<fieldset>
<legend>New Cafes</legend>
<label>Name<input type="text" name="name"></label>
<label>Address<input type="text" name="address"></label>
<label>Postcode<input type="text" name="address2"></label>
<label>Latitude<input type="text" name="lat" value="" id="addLat"></label>
<label>Longitude<input type="text" name="lng" value="" id="addLng"></label>
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit">
</form>


<p id="demo">Click the button to get your coordinates:</p>
<button onClick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<script>
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {
  x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;    
  }
</script>
```

To reiterate, I'd like the generated lat and lng results to automatically placed in the empty 'value' fields in the for so the user doesn't have to manually place in the boxes.

Any help very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the elements and add the value ?

```
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    document.getElementById('addLat').value = position.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById('addLng').value = position.coords.longitude;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vJvx4/)

Answer (score 0):

Basic JavaScript 101

Set the form element's `value`, inputs do not have `innerHTML`.

```
function showPosition(position) {
    document.getElementById("addLat").value = position.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById("addLng").value = position.coords.longitude;
}
```